# How do I install a custom Debian 10 .iso onto a USB Drive to make “Live”

Tags: debian

I am trying to customize a Debian 10 distro. I have tried both Respin and the Linux Live Kit. I am able to create a .iso file with both. My problem is when I try to make it live on the USB drive. I have tried the command line: `sudo dd bs=4M if=custom.iso of=/dev/sda conv=fdatasync` I have also tried that without the last part: `sudo dd bs=4M if=custom.iso of=/dev/sda`. I have tried to use the `Disks` program's Restore Disk Image feature. Additionally, I even tried to go over to Windows and use `Rufus`. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is '/dev/sda' your USB drive? If you can tell us what went wrong when you tried to boot from those. Also, the output of `file custom.iso` might help.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani The drive was ignored during the boot process. My boot order is correct because I have an Ubuntu USB drive that boots. Also '/dev/sda'  is the USB drive.

Comment: And what does the `file custom.iso` command say?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani file custom-live.iso output is: custom-live.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'Custom Debian Respin' (bootable)

Comment: `ls -l /dev/sda` please. Specifically, is it a device or a file?

Comment: @roaima ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 May 25 08:09 /dev/sda

Comment: Thanks. I've seen it before where `/dev/sda` somehow got replaced with a plain file output from `dd` (or whatever), so of course nothing ever got written to the USB device

Comment: @EduardoTrápani The size of the .iso is 3.3gb. Would that be a factor?

Comment: have you tried making the bootable usb with other software like etcher.io?

Comment: The size of the .iso would be a factor if your usb drive is, say, 2gb, i.e. less than 3.3gb.  Use `md5sum` or `sha256sum` to verify that your usb drive matches the .iso image.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ddrescue before to make a USB startup disk from the terminal. It worked well.

```
sudo ddrescue name-of-iso /dev/sdX --force -D
```